# Ubuntu 14.04 dispaly resolution problem

Tags: graphics, display, intel-graphics, screen, display-resolution

I am using Ubuntu for quite a while now. Just scrolling through the display settings I noticed that the screen resolution only gives me two options 1024x768 and 800x600 in a 4:3 aspect ratio while my monitor is capable of 1366x768 resolution at 60 hertz.

I do not have any external GPU, it's just Intel G41 onboard graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the proper display drivers.

Enter in System Configuration -> Software and updates, in the Additional drivers tab you should see a list with some Intel-GPU drivers (these used to be privatives).
Choose the most recent one and apply changes. Restart and you should be able to choose your screen resolution.